# Receiving Cell Broadcast for showing current location (Channel 50) in android

Tags: android

I've developed an Android application which shows current location (Channel 50) using **Cell Broadcast message**. I can't find any solution to enable/disable cell broadcast using my application. I enabled cell broadcast in standard SMS settings. The application is working well. One problem is that it also showing location name notification area of android and message as standard SMS application. It is annoying.

Is there any solution to prevent showing these messages in notification area and in standard messages and only show in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your BroadcastReceiver has a very high priority, and when you want the SMS not to go to the notifications and database, in your broadcast receiver call the following -

```
this.abortBroadcast();
```

Comment: I already done what you stated above, but no change.  i googled and somebody says that CellBroadcast is not ordered and so abortBroadcast not work.

Comment: Try giving the broadcast receiver very high priority.

Comment: hey @Abhinav I'm working on a similar project, and I've tried giving the highest priority, what I've found from my research is that Non ordered broadcasts cannot be aborted...